# How to add dependent jars to deploying plug-in

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I would to like to add the dependent jars to the update site plugin project in Eclipse. 
I followed
http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_an_update_site_%28site.xml%29%3F
but, it does not address the above issue. How to deal with the dependent jars with deploying plugin? Anybody please help with ideas.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using the update site stuff? That technology has been deprecated for several years? Do you just want to add some Jar files that your plugin depends on?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you are wanting to add additional Jar files to your plugin. You can do this by simply putting the Jar files into the top level directory of your plugin, and in the Classpath portion of the Runtime tab in the Plugin Manifest Editor you can specify the Jar file. This will automatically add it to the build path as well.

Some people prefer to make an extra plugin that contains nothing but external Jar files; you add the Jar files to this extra plugin the same way and then just use the Dependencies tab in the Plugin Manifest Editor to make your original plugin dependent on the Jar plugin.